# How do I add a network path to a name in excel name manager

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have code that works to add a path to a name in the name manager, but only for local paths.  When I try to use a network path, the name manager adds a colon before the first single backslash, which keeps the path from working. I have added code to debug, to remove colons, which it seems wasn't necessary.  The File open dialog does return the correct path. VBA writes it like this with debug.print:

```
`="\\win10box3\business\... ..."  `
```

When excel stores it in the name manager it stores it like this

```
`="\\Win10Box3:\Business\... ..."  `
```

I wrote code to remove the colon before adding the name, but I'm finding the path debug.prints correct before it is stored in the Name Manager, even before the loop to remove the colon.
The only solution I have found is to manually edit the path in the name manager to remove the colon

```vb
Sub GetPath()
Debug.Print "Start GetPath routine"
'This sub gets the path to a File defined by the user within the routine
'It then calls another sub that applies that path to a name in the worksheet.
' Before calling this routine, The name should first be searched for, and then verified, then opportunity given to change the name.
Dim MyPath As String        'String to hold the path to an excel spreadsheet exported from quickbooks
Dim NametoChange As String  'String that holds the name manager name to store the path under
Dim NameComment As String   'Comment to identify the name in the name manager
Dim PathLength As Long
Dim PathTemp As String

NametoChange = "PathToEmployeeWithholding"
NameComment = "This Name contains the Path to the 'Employee Withholding' worksheet exported from quickbooks using VBA"

MyMessage = "If you have not already exported and" & vbCrLf & "saved the employee withholding data from Quickbooks," & vbCrLf & "Please choose cancel and export it now"

DoIt = MsgBox(MyMessage, vbOKCancel)
Debug.Print DoIt

If DoIt = vbCancel Then
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    If .Show <> 0 Then
        MyPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

Debug.Print MyPath  'NOTE:This is producing the correct path.  It has no colon here...
                    'Where is the colon coming from?

'IT SEEMS NECESSARY TO REMOVE A COLON IF THE PATH IS A NETWORK PATH
'FIRST VERIFY IT IS NOT A DRIVE PATH... SHOULD BE IN THE FORM OF D:\
'WHAT IS UNIQUE IS THE COLON IS THE 2ND CHARACTER IN THE PATH IF A LOCAL DRIVE.
'TEST TO SEE IF THE INCREMENT IS 2.  IF IT IS, SKIP IT, AND REMOVE ALL OTHER COLONS

PathLength = Len(MyPath)
For i = 1 To PathLength
    If Not i = 2 Then
        If Not Mid(MyPath, i, 1) = ":" Then
            PathTemp = PathTemp & Mid(MyPath, i, 1)
        End If
    Else
        PathTemp = PathTemp & Mid(MyPath, i, 1)
    End If

    Debug.Print "i = " & i & " The current Character is " & _
       Mid(MyPath, i, 1) & xlcrlf & "the current PathTemp is " & PathTemp

Next

MyPath = PathTemp
Debug.Print MyPath

Debug.Print "Calling ChangeValueOfName Routine"; vbCrLf & vbCrLf
Call ChangeValueOfName(NametoChange, MyPath, NameComment)  'this routine stores the retrieved text string in the name manager
Debug.Print "Exit GetPath Routine" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
End Sub

Sub ChangeValueOfName(NametoChange As String, NewNameValue As String, Comment As String)
Debug.Print "Start changeValueOfName routine"

' ChangeValueOfNameManagerName Macro
' Changes the Value of a defined name in the Name Manager
'This should be used to change the name.
'Once the file is selected data needs to be imported to an array, and the
'Employee name values need to be checked against the worksheets in the workbook and against the recap sheet
'If changes are needed, it needs to write them into the workbook, including changing recap sheet and adding
'worksheets for any new employees

    With ThisWorkbook.Names(NametoChange)
        .Name = NametoChange
        .Comment = Comment
        RefersToR1C1 = _
        "=" & Chr(34) & NewNameValue & Chr(34)
    End With
    
    Debug.Print "The New Path added is " & "=" & Chr(34) & NewNameValue & Chr(34)
    Debug.Print "Return from ChangeValueOfName routine" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this: the path you're storing is saved in the Name's value as a quoted string, so it should be saved with no "automatic" modification.  Maybe try using `RefersTo` instead of `RefersToR1C1`

Comment: I wound up doing an office repair, and it solved the problem.  That seems crazy, but it's working now.